# Pandas - Create new dataframes based on ranked values in select columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with some columns containing numerical data and other containing text. This is basically what it looks like:

```
Age    Weight    Blood Sugar    Study Group    Gender    Notes
29     195       126            B              Female    notes of some kind
34     180       140            B              Male      different set of notes
48     220       111            C              Male      blah blah
55     189       109            C              Male      some more notes
```

I want to create sub-divisions of the data frame based on rankings of the numerical data columns. For example, if I need the 2 oldest patients my new dataframe will look like this:

```
Age    Weight    Blood Sugar    Study Group    Gender    Notes
48     220       111            C              Male      blah blah
55     189       109            C              Male      some more notes
```

The [rank](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) function looks like it could be useful. I figure I could run:

```
df2 = rank.df(axis=0)
```

and then find some way to use the index of **df2** to pull rows from **df** into new dataframes. Something along the lines of:

```
cutoff = df2[df2 > 10]
# DELETE ROWS WITH NaN VALUES IN THE COLUMNS OF INTEREST
```

This feels a bit clunky though. I'm hoping there's a more straight-forward way to say,

"Pandas, I want a new dataframe with the 15 oldest people in this one. Great! Now I want a new dataframe with the 20 youngest people, etc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to sort the DataFrame by age:

```
df = df.sort('Age')
```

Then age of the n-th youngest person by `df['Age'].values[n]` and the age of the n-th oldest person by `df['Age'].values[-n]`.

Therefore, to view a DataFrame with the people who are of the 15 oldest ages, you could do:

```
df[df['Age'] >= df['Age'].values[-15]]
```

Alternatively, if you simply want to limit by the number of rows returned (e.g. don't mind that there may be 20 people sharing the oldest age of, say, 55), you could just use the `head` and `tail` methods on the sorted DataFrame...

```
df_age = df.sort('Age', ascending=False)
```

...then `df_age.head(15)` would view 15 of the people, `df_age.tail(20)` would view 20 of the youngest people.